# Nginx configuration to send logs to remote server

Tags: nginx, logging, rsyslog

I have remote server configuration includes ip and port and filter with local tag as 'local2' as customtemplate.conf in rsyslogd folder in /etc/rsyslog/rsyslogd, i need to send the local nginx logs to remote server what changes need to be done in nginx.conf file and rsyslog.conf tosend logs to remote server

Comment: I think [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1469810/1567444) on askUbuntu should answer your question.